# How do you compare two variables in an if statement?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program where a user tries to guess the amount of times two dice have to roll to reach the totalsum of 100.

I've finished the loop but now I'm stuck on the point where I want the program to compare the two variables. I've googled but nothing has been coming up regarding the issue.

In regards to the code, here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int min_value=1;
const int max_value=6;
int die1,die2,sum,totalRolls, totalSum, prediction;
unsigned seed = time(0);
srand(seed);
sum=0;
totalRolls=0;
totalSum=0;
cout << "How many rolls will it take to reach a total of 100?\n";
cin >> prediction;

while (totalSum <= 100)
{
    cout << "Rolling the die\n";
    die1=(rand() % (max_value - min_value + 1) + min_value); 
    die2=(rand() % (max_value - min_value + 1) + min_value);

    cout << die1 << endl;
    cout << die2 << endl;
    sum=die1+die2;
    totalSum+=sum;
    cout << "Your current total is " << totalSum << endl;
    totalRolls++;
    cout << "Last roll number = " << totalRolls << endl;

}

if (totalRolls <= 5)
    {
    cout << "Amazing!\n";   
    }   

else if (totalRolls <=10)
    {
    cout << "Good\n";
    }
else if (totalRolls <= 15)
    {
    cout << "Okay\n";
    }
else if (totalRolls <= 20)
    {
    cout << "Try harder\n";
    }
system("Pause");
return 0;

}
```

I honestly just don't know how to compare the predicted total number of rolls compared to the actual rolls it took.

Comment: `if(variable1 == variable2)`? Not sure what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my post but I need to compare them ln a way where the program knows if the predicted amount of rolls is within specific value eg within (+ or -) 5, 10, 15, and 20 rolls. For example, if I predicted that it took 15 rolls in order to reach 100. The program rolls, and it turns out that it took 17 rolls. In that specific instance, I want the program to prompt the user with "excellent" and so on and so forth just depending on how well they predicted.

Comment: This is simple math. `abs(predicted - actual)` gives you the (positive) difference.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck for the longest time. lol.